# Woocommerce product page - Display problem

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, display, yoast

I have a problem with the woocommerce product page.
The meta title of Yoast is displayed on a vertical line. I've never seen this before. You can get a preview of it on the attached screenshot. The problem occurred after an update of yoast.

My wordpress and all my plugins are up to date

Thank you for your help

[Problem - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfNZR.png)

Comment: This is probably a problem with the CSS for this particular column. The theme that you are using have this problem. If you don't know about programming with HTML and CSS, the only solutions are: change the theme or try to contact the people who made this theme.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
But I can't change the theme, it. This is an online store and the owner cannot afford to put his site in continuous maintenance. 

I can programming but, I think that the next time I update my changes will cause problems. 

I will try to contact the people who made this theme.

Comment: Use the inspector in your browser by pressing F12. You will be able inspect and  change the CSS and see whats works but this can't save the code source.

Comment: I already use the inspector and I was able to see a "width:100%;" on the class "widefat", when I disable it, my page is displayed correctly. 
But I can't write it in my "style.css" in my theme folder.
After a quicksearch, this class is located in my admin folder of wordpress.

I heard about a solution with a "function" file that will allow me to create a condition to overwrite this "width:100%". 

What do you think about it ?

Comment: Can you share your source about this solution with a "function" file? It may works but to me, it's a dirty patch that will suck you time. Do you really don't have access to edit the style.css associated with this "Widefat" class? It would be a lot easier to just edit it.

Comment: My source is not on the internet I'm sorry. I try to find help everywhere ahahah. 
So, I share your opinion about this solution but right now I don't have anything better. 

I appreciate your interest in my problem, thank you

I think there is a conflict with other plugins (I didn't make this site, I just manage it). There are a lot of them. The main solution would be to isolate them one by one, but it's an online store, the site should be paused and I can't do that for the moment.